# Prevent Windows key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can prevent Alt key in Javascript with these codes:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event) 
{
    if(event.altKey == true)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

But if I want to prevent Win key from taking any default actions, can I?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't block it since the Win Key is applied outside the scope of the browser, on a lower level. The same goes for combinations like `Ctrl+Alt+Del` and `Ctrl+Shift+Esc`.

However, if you just want to know if it was clicked and make it trigger an action you can do it like this:

```js
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.key == "Meta") {
    // event.preventDefault(); //Won't work
    console.log("Win Key was clicked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```