# Capture Windows key on Chromium

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to capture the Windows-key and/or Mac-OS functional key without causing the system menu to appear. tried the following with JQuery it works BUT the system menu is still being shown.

```
  $(document.body).keydown(function (evt) {



   if(evt.keyCode === 91){
     evt.stopPropagation();
       CWindowManager.getInstance().getStartMenu.toggle();
        }


  });
```

This can be done since the VMWare eSXI client does just that (when connecting to remote UI sessions) without installing any system-addons I believe? Not that this might be especially true when user agreed to operate in full-screen mode as that is when Chromium allows more special key-combinations to pass-through.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42173952/990473